# How to configure MySQL Workbench to not require SSL encryption

Tags: mysql, ssl, mysql-workbench

I'm trying not to enable using ssl for my connection, but I only have these 3 options in MySQL Workbench without 'No' and 'If Available' options.
[image]

I tried re-installing MySQL Workbench, but it doesn't work. What am I supposed to do now??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrade to 8.0.27. Had no clue how to solve it.

I downgraded MySQL Workbench back to 8.0.19, and the 'No' and 'If Available' options came back.

Maybe they just want you to buy Navicat I guess.

Comment: Yes, that works for me too!!

Comment: Thank you for this.  Utterly ridiculous for Oracle to do this.  I truly hope it's just a bug.

Comment: Reverting back to 8.0.26 was enough to get the options back.

Comment: Will be fixed in [8.0.28](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105327)

Answer (score 61):

You can go to the Advanced tab and type the following in the Others field:

> useSSL=0

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Works in 8.0.27. I've checked it against a MariaDB server. So there's no need to downgrade

Comment: This should be marked as answer. [Will be fixed in 8.0.28](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105327)

Comment: The SSL tab doesn't show a "No SSL" option and this solution is not intuitive. Thank you, you saved me

Comment: This works but it doesn't seem to keep the setting in that box, so the next time you enter that tab it's gone (and I think you need to re-enter it to get it to work again)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a bunch. My WB version is 8.0.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of downgrading you can also edit the file that stores the connection details with a different editor. This works for at least 8.0.27.

Open `/home/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml`.

Set the value to `0` for the following for each connection you want to use without SSL:

```
<value type="int" key="useSSL">0</value>
```

Note that you'd have to repeat the steps if you edit the connection with the workbench again afterwards.

Comment: On macos the location is `/System/Volumes/Data/Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/connections.xml`

Comment: The file location in Windows 10 is C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench

Comment: This is perfect, just remember to keep an edited copy of the file handy as it may overwrite on close as well.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench Community version 8.0.28 is released and fix it -
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

ssl certificates really guarantee a secure connection. But locally you shouldn't request a certificate..26 which by default makes use of ssl if it is available, otherwise in the new version it is a requirement.

here is the download link

[choose version 8.0.26 here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/)